# Does win32 TextOut() complete asynchronously?

Tags: winapi, graphics, gdi

This should be a simple google or MSDN answer - but I have come up short in searching.  I have a small win32 application that uses GDI for a lot of drawing.  I have observed that when I place a "label" with TextOut() on my memory Device Context, then BitBlt immediately after the TextOut() call, the text shows up intermittently, flickering in and out.  The BitBlt() is in another thread, but I have a critical section to guard from copying the graphic under work.  When I put the TextOut() earlier in the flow, i.e. not close to the BitBlt(), it always shows up.  All I can figure is that TextOut() returns before completion.. can anyone point me to documentation or suggest another theory?

FYI - I have already checked out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145133(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks!

Comment: I would highly recommend checking out direct2d (3d if you are smart) and forget that deprecated GDI

Comment: Not really the question Ulterior... the question is if TextOut() completes asynchronously.  We have applications that use DirectDraw, Direct3D, GDI... each have their place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.  [GdiFlush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144844%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is the call to force all GDI updates to the video adapter.

Lots of other ways to shoot your foot.  GDI is not thread-safe at all so don't expect miracles, I guess.